# How can I use \SI from siunitx inside \replaced from changes?

Tags: siunitx, changes

I'm trying to record some changes using the changes package - I've already done a lot of the text, and had to work around display maths but I've got a simple value typeset using siunitx, and changing that value doesn't appear to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{changes}
\begin{document}
    \replaced{\SI{1}{\volt}}{\SI{2}{\volt}}
\end{document}
```

gives:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\UL@stop ...z@ \else \UL@putbox \fi \else \egroup 
                                                  \egroup \UL@putbox \fi \if...
l.5 ...\SI{1}{\volt}}{\SI{2}{\volt}}
```

If I continue to compile (getting the same error again and 2 `missing } inserted`s, the output is actually exactly as expected:

[image: surprisingly correct output of above code]

adding `\protect` before the `\SI` gives exactly the same error, and of course trying `\SI{\replaced{1}{2}}{\volt}` was never going to work:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! siunitx error: "invalid-token-in-number"
! 
! Invalid token '\let ' in numerical input.
! 
! See the siunitx documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................
```

Is there some workaround that will get this to run without errors?  I don't really want to run in nonstopmode in case of "real" errors, and besides, I used a build script that's designed to stop on errors.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem here is actually an interaction with the `\sout` command from the `ulem` package. Essentially, there is a clash over the insertion of a `\penalty` between the number and the unit: `ulem` alters how this expects to work and that doesn't agree with the box/grouping in `siunitx`. I've not traced it all back to a minimal example of the low-level code, but that probably wouldn't help in any case (at least without quite a bit of effort). What you can do is simply disable the insertion of a penalty. There isn't an interface for this (one of the few things not in the options for `siunitx`!) so at the moment a low-level redefinition is required

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{changes}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \__siunitx_unit_output_number_sep:
  \__siunitx_unit_output_number_sep_aux:
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
    \replaced{\SI{1}{\volt}}{\SI{2}{\volt}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's great, thank you.  But is there a downside - i.e. should I be undoing this fix when I switch from `[draft]` to `[final]`?

Comment: @ChrisH Yes, I would. The penalty is there to prevent or at least discourage a line break between the number and the unit.

Comment: Now I think about it, I'm using a non-breaking space as my separator, so on the face of it I shouldn't need a penalty anyway.  But of course I've no way of knowing whether it could break despite this.

Answer (score 2):

An easy workaround for this is to replace `\SI{x}{y}` for `\num{x}\,\si{y}`, which should produce an equivalent result in most cases and doesn't produce the error:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{changes}
\begin{document}
    \replaced{\SI{1}{\volt}}{\num{2}\,\si{\volt}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define your own deletion markup no depending on the ulem package, e.g.:

```
\usepackage{changes}
\setdeletedmarkup{---#1---}
```

Downside of this approach is that the deleted markup does not match expectations of being striked out.

See example in https://gitlab.com/ekleinod/changes/tree/master/testfiles/t61-siunitx

As I cannot answer the duplicate question [Undocumented incompatibility between changes and siunitx?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/495288/undocumented-incompatibility-between-changes-and-siunitx/) here is the link for the corresponding issue tracker [Incompatibility with siunitx and maybe other packages](https://gitlab.com/ekleinod/changes/issues/61)

Disclaimer: I am the author of the package.

Answer (score -2):

Wrap `\SI` inside a `\mbox`:
`\mbox{\SI{}}`.
Take into account that the word will continue along the line (no breakup).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please explain better how that can solve the given issue ...