# Undocumented incompatibility between changes and siunitx?

Tags: siunitx, changes

I am currently using the `changes` package to track some modifications in a document, along with the `siunitx` package for number formatting.

Whenever I try to have a `\SI{}{}` call iside a `\replaced{}{}` or `\deleted{}` call, `pdflatex` throws me an error though the ouput file seems fine.

This issue does not seem to be documented, either in the user manual or on the git repo.

Here is a MWE to illustrate the issue

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{changes}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
This is a new length of \SI{8}{\meter};
This is a new length of \deleted{\SI{8}{\meter}}.
This is a new length of \replaced{\SI{8}{\meter}}{\SI{3}{\meter}}.
\end{document}
```

Any idea how to remove this error, as it does not seem to impact the result ?

EDIT : [Here is the link to the issue on the Git repo](https://gitlab.com/ekleinod/changes/issues/61)

Comment: I faced exactly this issue myself finalising my thesis, so I knew it had come up before

Comment: @ChrisH same situation here, thanks for the link. Sometimes it is quite difficult to find the duplicates...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`changes` uses internally the `ulem` package, and this can't handle complicated macros. You normally should hide them in a `\mbox`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{changes}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
This is a new length of \SI{8}{\meter};
This is a new length of \deleted{\mbox{\SI{8}{\meter}}}.
This is a new length of \replaced{\mbox{\SI{8}{\meter}}}{\mbox{\SI{3}{\meter}}}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a way to apply such `\mbox` to all `\deleted` calls, with a `\renewcommand` maybe ?

Answer (score 4):

You can provisionally redefine `\SI` to use `\mbox` around it.

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{changes}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand \SI { o m o m } {
 \mbox{
   \bool_set_false:N \l__siunitx_font_set_bool
   \IfNoValueTF {#1}
     { \__siunitx_combined:nnnn { } {#2} {#3} {#4} }
     {
       \keys_set:nn { siunitx } {#1}
       \__siunitx_combined:nnnn {#1} {#2} {#3} {#4}
     }
 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

This is a new length of \SI{8}{\meter};
This is a new length of \deleted{\SI{8}{\meter}}.
This is a new length of \replaced{\SI{8}{\meter}}{\SI{3}{\meter}}.

\end{document}
```

I'd prefer a `changes` method that avoids striking out (color would be sufficient).

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{changes}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\setdeletedmarkup{\textcolor{red}{#1}}

\begin{document}

This is a new length of \SI{8}{\meter};
This is a new length of \deleted{\SI{8}{\meter}}.
This is a new length of \replaced{\SI{8}{\meter}}{\SI{3}{\meter}}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am flying blind here, but would it not be better to patch `changes` instead ? The error popped up with `siunitx` but it may also happen with other commands right.

Comment: BTW, I just opened an issue on the git repo of the package

Comment: @BambOo The problem is that `mbox` can not be broken across lines... that's not a problem for `\SI{}{}`, but can be for long `\deleted{...}` phrases...

Comment: @Rmano I did not see that, you're right !